# From his confession results

Tags: prepositions

*From his confession results that the father raped his own daughter.*

Recently I have posted a question on movies.stackexchange.com. The sentence above is the part of my post. I am not sure whether "it" should not be before "results". I have doubts even if the clause was not corrected until now.

Comment: This looks like proofreading to me. It's highly stilted / formal / archaic phrasing, which simply makes it more noticeable that ***it*** has been "deleted" (which is generally *valid*, just very clumsy and confusing as used here). Or you could suppose the deletion / suppression is of ***the fact that*** immediately *after* that awkward verb usage of ***results***. Personally, I'd go for a wholesale rewrite.

Comment: fwiw, I have no problem with *From quantum theory **arises** an unavoidable consequence* (there's always an element of uncertainty, for example). There's no special *syntactic* reason why ***to arise*** should be any different to ***to result***, where they both just mean ***to come about, transpire.*** But I really couldn't approve of *From quantum theory **results** that very consequence*.

Comment: OK. But where is the subject of my sentence when "it" is not necessary?

Comment: You need **it** as a placeholder for the content-clause.  *From his confession, it turns out that the father ....*  There **it turns out** basically means "we discover".

Comment: "From his confession *came* results that the father raped his own daughter." keeping in mind *results* is a noun (facts from the confession). I wouldn't try to use it as a verb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's transpose the order of the clauses and make the *that*-clause the subject of your verb:

> That the father raped his own daughter results from his confession.

This is awkward, unidiomatic English, not because the *that*-clause is made the subject, but because **results** is not how we would express the idea that we learn this fact from his confession.

> It so happens, as we learn from his confession, that he raped his own
>   daughter.
>
> We learn from his confession that he raped his own daughter.
>
> From his confession, it turns out that he raped his own daughter.
>
> It turns out from his confession he raped his own daughter.

It is the **knowledge** that he raped his own daughter which results from the confession; the fact itself (which is what is expressed by the *that*-clause) is not knowledge of the fact.